# My Roblox script only works for the first player that joins the game

Tags: lua, roblox

This script is run from within the workspace and should update the local GUI value for the local player once they interact with the Proximity Prompt (prox)

```
player = game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Wait()
repeat wait() until player.Character
local repStore = game.ReplicatedStorage
local remoteEvent = repStore["Remote Events"]:WaitForChild("avatarView")
local values = player.Values
local prox = script.Parent.viewAvatar

prox.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    values["Total Price"].Value = "R15 MAN"
    remoteEvent:FireClient(player)
end)
```

The script works flawlessly, however only for the first person that joins the game, for every player afterwards they will get the default values and it wont update them like it should in the script.

I will note that the values are cloned from ReplicatedStorage and placed inside the local player, but this is not an issue as I have done a team test and each player gets the cloned values, but only the first players' values update.

The following is the code which responds to the remoteEvent in the first script. I cant imagine the fault is with this code as the final line which opens the shop's GUI still functions. However i felt it was useful to include this just incase.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
repeat wait() until player.Character
local repStore = game.ReplicatedStorage
local remoteEvent = repStore["Remote Events"]:WaitForChild("avatarView")
local shop = script.Parent.Main
local values = player.Values
local totalPrice = values["Total Price"]

remoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    shop.Price.Text = totalPrice.Value
    wait(0.2)
    shop.Visible = true
end)
```

I would like to say that I have tried this inside Roblox Studio, No errors appear.
I have tried this as a normal Roblox experience and it still does not work.

I have tried changing the lines of code which wait for the player to load in the game as I believe this is where the fault is. However I am unable to get it to work, still.

Comment: Maybe because you have two variable named "player" so it only fires to the first player that joined the server. Try changing the variable name inside the proxy function.

Comment: @Vector3 I amended the script and changed the variable in the proxy function to "plr." Still getting the same problem im afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this.

```lua
values["Total Price"].Value = "R15 MAN"
```

You can do something like this. Since Values is only for the first player to join the server. Hope this helps.

```lua
player.Values["Total Price"].Value = "R15 MAN"
```

Comment: I gave this a go and im still experiencing the same issues. The value updates only work for the first player that joins the game, I want it to work for everybody.

Comment: @DanielCrunkhurn did you name the parameter "player". If you named it something else make sure to change it.

Comment: the script looks like the initial one I wrote up, Except the prox function variable is now "plr" and I have the edited line from your answer to read "player.Values["Total Price"].Value = "R15 MAN"". I can see how this would all work in theory. I am unsure why it is not working? If I understand correctly you want me to change the name of the variable "player"?

Comment: Just got home and changed the parameter back to player from plr and its worked! Thanks so much.